# Box-shadow doesn't fit element's sides

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, box-shadow

> Note: don't focus on the **purpose** of this code, it's only a minimalist example to highlight the issue encoutered.

When I'm using the `box-shadow` property, it sometimes doesn't fit the element's sides, resulting by a 1px (or less) margin between the element and its shadow. Here is an example, using `transform` to raise the issue (I think this is not the only way to get it):

```css
h1 {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px 55px;
  background: black;
  box-shadow: 30px 0 0 black, -30px 0 0 black;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 50px;
  /* I use 0.5px to show the bug, I would use n% in real conditions */
  transform: translate(0.5px, 0); 
}
h1 a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h1><a href="#">Foo</a></h1>
```

If you don't see anything, try to look the full-screen snippet, and resize your browser (I got the issue with Chrome and Firefox). Below is a picture with several screenshots I made, and the (obvious) expected result:

[image]

Does anybody faced this issue?
Looks like a browser one, but can we find a workaround to avoid these margins?

### EDIT

I've found something new: if I set a box-shadow on a single side, the gap doesn't occurs, using Chrome (it's still here with Firefox):

```css
h1 {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px 55px;
  background: black;
  box-shadow: 30px 0 0 black, -30px 0 0 black;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 50px;
  /* I use 0.5px to show the bug, I would use n% in real conditions */
  transform: translate(0.5px, 20px); 
}
h1 a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1:nth-child(2) {
  box-shadow: 30px 0 0 black;    
}
h1:nth-child(3) {
  box-shadow: -30px 0 0 black;    
}
```

```html
<h1><a href="#">Foo</a></h1>
<h1><a href="#">Foo</a></h1>
<h1><a href="#">Foo</a></h1>
```

[image]

Comment: what's the purpose of `transform: translate(0.5px, 0);` ? what if you remove it?

Comment: Wondering what **half** a pixel looks like. Rounding would always be an issue...no?

Comment: Its purpose it to ensure you'll see the bug (whatever your screen resolution). But it happens to me to use percents in translation, which results by the same bug: `transform: translate(25%, 0);`

Comment: Again, using % would also cause rounding issues...I'm curious as to what this box-shadow is actually for. It seems a curious option for a simple link.

Comment: Don't focus on the example :) I made it as simple as possible to highlight the issue. My code is far more complex, and this could happen with any box-shadow. I added a note for future readers.

Comment: Do you have somewhere with a **live** example (not forced) that actually demonstrates the issue in a working environment,

Comment: Unfortunately not, the related project is still private.

Comment: [adding a border](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/kgv5ut9x/) corrected the issue for me (chrome 40 win7)

Comment: @zessx My recent post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418486/css3-hexagon-shape-with-a-border-outline/28835139#28835139) is suffering from the same issue which i was going to ask!

Comment: Box shadow seems to create the jagging problem. see this : [img](http://i.stack.imgur.com/j8tWL.png)

Comment: @web-tiki Great tip, even if it doesn't worked on my project (damn...)

Comment: Not sure if this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223880/small-space-between-box-shadow-and-div-when-alpha-set (or a google search for [**box-shadow gap**](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=box+shadow+gap&tbs=qdr:y) turns up some others.)

Comment: Could you use pseudo-elements instead of the box-shadow?

Comment: @Paulie_D Not really. The real goal is to have a multiline title, with left/right padding on **every** line.

Comment: Like this? - http://jsfiddle.net/oonnzmkb/

Comment: @Paulie_D I forgot a point, sorry. I need an extra 1px margin between each line (this last point explains why I came to a darker solution)

Comment: Any thoughts on this - https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-padded-text/

Comment: I precisely use one of the methods described in this article.

Answer (score 0):

This CSS works:

```
h1 {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  background: green;
  box-shadow: 30px 0 0 black;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 50px;
  /* I use 0.5px to show the bug, I would use n% in real conditions */
  transform: translate(0.5px, 0); 
}
h1 a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here is a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/jvo72exn/10/).
The colors you were using (black on black) made the slight difference you saw. Changing the colors will do it.

Comment: That's wrong, I still have the gap. But I've find something new with your code. **The gap only occurs when I've got a box-shadow on both sides (Chrome only).**

Comment: `transform:translate(.5px, 0);` You are moving the `h1` and not the box-shadow. Try getting rid of the `transform`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome Version 42.0.2311.90 m

When the browser resolution changes (from about 25% to 500%) and
**the translate y-axis is 0 or 0px**
the gap occurs. Example code:

```
    transform: translate(0.5px, 0); 
    transform: translate(0.5px, 0px); 
    transform: translate(7px, 0); 
    transform: translate(7px, 0px);
```

Using zessx's **EDIT**, showing 3 examples on output, I got the same result he did for

```
    transform: translate(0.5px, 20px);
```

But when I removed one "px" on either axis there was NO gap.  Examples:

```
    transform: translate(0.5px, 20);
    transform: translate(0.5px, 1);
    transform: translate(0.5, 20px); 
    transform: translate(0, 20px);
```

Gap moves (L to R to gone) only for shadow-box on both sides as resolution changes in Chrome, as stated by **zessx**