# hairline rendering on box-shadow

Tags: css, frontend, rendering, blur

I'm trying to troubleshoot weird `box-shadow` behavior. I have the property set on a bottom nav and while I'm expecting a smooth blur transition from the background of the div to the `box-shadow` I'm getting a hardline gap between the two. See [rendered image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oORpj.png). Any thoughts on why?

```
.nav {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 3rem 2.5rem 7rem 2.5rem;
    width: 100vw;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: baseline;
    background-color: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.85);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 50px rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.85);
    z-index: 9991;
}
```

Comment: There isn’t anything in the CSS you show which is creating the hairline, at least on my system. Can you post a working example?

Comment: I don’t see any gap on that jsfiddle either, but I am only looking at it on IOS Safari. What browser/ system is giving you the problem and I’ll see if I can use that.

Comment: @AHaworth totally, after doing more research I discovered a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27223880/small-space-between-box-shadow-and-div-when-alpha-set). Playing around with different height values produced varying level of success – defining it in absolute, pixel terms wasn't ideal so I switched over to using a gradient. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4ksbyu8/).

Comment: Chrome on a Macbook Pro 16". It's more apparent on my 5K screen though when I zoom in close enough the partial pixels reconcile and the gap disappears.