# Box-shadow in IE present a transparent line/border

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, box-shadow

I'm trying to create a tile component in HTML that allow to have an image and text as show:

[image: IE rendering]

As you can see there are two lines which are only visible in IE. I had remove the outline and any border but still doesn't change anything.

Do you have any Idea how to solve this?

```css
 .tiles-container{
  max-width: 350px;
 }
 
 .tile-banner{
   position: relative;
 }
 
 
 .tiles-container .tile-banner .tile-webcontrol-container {
    height: 200px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.tiles-container .tile-title-container {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 20px;
    bottom: 16px;
    margin-right: 60px;
}

.tiles-container .tile-title-container .tile-title {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #243e7b;
    padding-top: 4.85px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 0 0 #fff, -10px 0 0 #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 0 0 #fff, -10px 0 0 #fff;
    box-shadow: 10px 0 0 #fff, -10px 0 0 #fff;
    box-decoration-break: clone;
    line-height: 1.55em;
}
```

```html
<div class="tiles-container">
<div class="tile-banner">
  <div class="tile-webcontrol-container" id="6878d5d7-31df-4ab4-9019-bdf129eff4c4" style="background-position: center; background-image: url('//c1.staticflickr.com/4/3956/15495749937_b4ee958d86_h.jpg'); background-size: cover;">
    <div class="ris-container"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tile-title-container">
    <span class="tile-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. bla bla</span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your problem is well known. And cannot be fixed unless you use inline-block or block elements. At least no one found a solution yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove 1px transparent space from CSS box-shadow in IE11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161981/remove-1px-transparent-space-from-css-box-shadow-in-ie11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display:block` or `inline-block` in the `span`

CSS:

```
  .tiles-container .tile-title-container .tile-title {
     background-color: #fff;
     color: #243e7b;
     padding-top: 4.85px;
     padding-bottom: 5px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 0 0 #fff, -10px 0 0 #fff;
     -moz-box-shadow: 10px 0 0 #fff, -10px 0 0 #fff;
     box-shadow: 10px 0 0 #fff, -10px 0 0 #fff;
     box-decoration-break: clone;
     line-height: 1.55em;
     display: block;
   }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/2159/

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, but I need to keep the area around the label as it is. I can't use the display: block for the final solution

Comment: @JuanJardim As per your requirements, I suggest you use two different spans for the text with the same class. Your problem will be solved.